# ImportError: No module named 'skimage', but i have all dependencies and scikit-image installed

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, raspbian, scikit-image

[image: screenshot for dependencies and scikit-image]

I tried to run a program in python3.4, but it always give me this error message

```
from skimage import feature
```

ImportError: No module named 'skimage'

I search the internet for answers here and there, tried some solutions, but i keep getting the error. But then I tried to run the exact same program in python2.7, and it did not give any error mesaage so I assume that it runs well in python2.7. Is there anyway I can get this program running in python3.4?

Answer (score 4):

You have it installed in your Python 2 libraries. You should install it in your Python 3 libraries too:

```
$ pip3 install scikit-image
```

Comment: I already did that, but it still give the same error message(I forgot wether I was inside cvx or not). Extra info, I put python2 and python3 in different virtual envs. That (cvx) virtualenv is for python3. Should I get into virtual env for pyhton3 and run `$ pip3 install scikit-image` ?@Mureinik

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I have the `scikit-image` package installed in Python 3 and when I ran:

```
$ ./<filename.py>
```

I got the same error. Turns out Python 2 was running. Try running:

```
$ python3 ./<filename.py>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed python via Anaconda, you can run the following. It fixed the error.

```
conda install --yes -c conda-forge scikit-image
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried every possible method within the environment but failed terribly until I used `sudo`.

What did work:

```
sudo pip install scikit-image
```

What didn't work

```
pip install scikit-image 
conda install scikit-image 
conda install -c anaconda scikit-image  
conda install --yes -c conda-forge scikit-image 
pip3 install scikit-image
```